# How to create CSS grid system with merged cells

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:

[image]

As you can see, the cards in the middle column occupy multiple grids, in order to give it that effect.

What I have:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    ". . ."
    ". . ."
    ". . .";
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```

However, my approach definitely isn't the most sustainable, nor are my cards rendering in the correct order (cards go from 1, 7, 2, 3 etc ..).

I haven't seen an approach where using `CSS grid`, a layout like the image has been achieved, so wondering if `CSS grid` is the best solution here?

Comment: Your error is assuming a 3 row grid. If you make it 6 rows with each element spanning 2, you can adjust the layout as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you mostly have to change the behavior of your grid container.

- Adding `grid-auto-flow: column;` fixes the issue of the elements moving in rows.
- Doubling the number of rows means that you can work "by halves" when positioning our elements.
- On the grid elements, adding `grid-row: span 2` sets them to occupy a whole area in your design
- Then all you have to do is tell the first one and second to last one to start on the second row.
- If you were going to iterate this over more than 3 columns, it would by every 7th element minus the first one ( `.grid-item:nth-child(7n-1)`) instead of `nth-to-last`. In that case, you'd also have to define your grid differently, similar to below.

```
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 6, auto );
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
```

You can also remove the grid-area definition.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 0px 0px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-row: span 2;
  
}

.grid-item:nth-child(1), .grid-item:nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```